# Limit title length

Tags: title

It almost work correctly, but alwas return the same menu name:
On home all menu elements name home
on contact all menu elements name contact

```
function max_title_length( $title ) {
    global $post;
    $id = ($post->ID);
    $title = get_post( $id )->post_title;
    $max = 20;
    if( strlen( $title ) > $max ) {
        return substr( $title, 0, $max ). " &hellip;";  
    }
    else {
        return $title;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'max_title_length');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're not using the filter correctly. The `the_title` filter passes the title to be filtered as the `$title` argument, but you're overwriting it with this code:

```
global $post;
$id = ($post->ID);
$title = get_post( $id )->post_title;
```

That code's completely unnecessary because the title is already available in your function:

```
function max_title_length( $title ) {
```

So simply remove those lines to filter the correct title:

```
function max_title_length( $title ) {
    $max = 20;

    if ( strlen( $title ) > $max ) {
        return substr( $title, 0, $max ) . ' &hellip;';  
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'max_title_length' );
```

Just be aware that — as you've experienced — the `the_title` filter applies to all titles, including posts, pages, and *menu items*. So if you only want your code to apply to titles output within The Loop, you can use the `in_the_loop()` function:

```
function max_title_length( $title ) {
    $max = 20;

    if ( in_the_loop() && strlen( $title ) > $max ) {
        return substr( $title, 0, $max ) . ' &hellip;';  
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'max_title_length' );
```

Comment: With in_the_loop() function, it limit just title from ads(using classipress), rest posts and custom posts not working.

Comment: It sounds like you might be doing something weird with your loop then. Remove it if it's causing problems, but I can't offer any more advice without seeing the relevant template.

Comment: in classipress theme ads it's like post, and this loop working, but working just for ads, not working for posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
function max_title_length($title) {
    if(is_front_page()){
        $max = 8;  
    }
    elseif(is_single()){
        $max = 5;
    }
    else{
        $max = 15;
    }


    if (strlen( $title ) > $max ) {
        return substr( $title, 0, $max ) . ' &hellip;';  
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'max_title_length' );
```

it still cut the menu title. in_the_loop() function not working.

Answer (score -1):

```
function max_title_length( $title ) {    
    $max = 20;
    if ( strlen( $title ) > $max ) {
       $title = substr( $title, 0, $max ) . ' &hellip;';  
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'max_title_length' );
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! While your answer looks like it's technically correct and should work for the OP, it's short on details and explanation. Please see [How do I write a good answer?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the site's Help section.